# A question about the proof of Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, cv.complex-variables, st.statistics

I was reading the proof of Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem in http://www.math.kit.edu/iana3/lehre/fourierana2014w/media/rieszthorinproof.pdf
and get stuck at the last step. We construct the complex function
\begin{equation*}
   F(z)=\int g_zTf_z=\sum_{i,j}|a_i|^{\frac{p}{p(z)}}\frac{a_i}{|a_i|}|b_j|^{\frac{q}{q(z)}}\frac{b_j}{|b_j|}\int_{B_j}T\chi_{A_i}
\end{equation*}
and finally we have
\begin{equation*}
   \sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}F(iy)=\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\int g_{yi}Tf_{yi}\leq \|T\|_{L_{p_0}(\mathbb{C}^n)\rightarrow L_{q_0}(\mathbb{C}^n)}\|g_{yi}\|_{L_{q_0}}\|f_{yi}\|_{L_{p_0}}
\end{equation*}
However, if we come back to the theorem, what we actually want to show is
\begin{equation} 
 \sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}F(iy)\leq N_0\|g_{yi}\|_{L_{q_0}} \|f_{yi}\|_{L_{p_0}}=\|T\|_{L_{p_0}(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L_{q_0}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\|g_{yi}\|_{L_{q_0}} \|f_{yi}\|_{L_{p_0}}
\end{equation}
I understand that $\|g_{yi}\|_{L_{q_0}}=\|g_0\|_{L_{q_0}}$ and $\|f_{yi}\|_{L_{p_0}}=\|f_0\|_{L_{p_0}}$, but as we know the complex norm is never smaller than real norm. So we need to show
\begin{equation*}
   \|T\|_{L_{p_0}(\mathbb{C}^n)\rightarrow L_{q_0}(\mathbb{C}^n)}=\|T\|_{L_{p_0}(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L_{q_0}(\mathbb{R}^n)}
\end{equation*}
 which is not obvious. Moreover, if we have to add a constant $C$ such that
\begin{equation*}
   \|T\|_{L_{p_0}(\mathbb{C}^n)\rightarrow L_{q_0}(\mathbb{C}^n)}\leq C\|T\|_{L_{p_0}(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L_{q_0}(\mathbb{R}^n)}
\end{equation*}
Then the statement of this theorem must be modified accordingly.  I tried to simplify it into matrix case and regard the linear map $T$ as an $n\times n$ matrix, then $T:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$ can be looked as another $2n\times 2n$ matrix $T\otimes I_2$, however, the $L_p$ norm in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is different from that in $\mathbb{C}^n$ when $p\neq 2$.

In conclusion, my questions are:

(1) Is the statement of Riesz-Thorin theorem in the above website true for real linear map $T$? If it is true, how to prove it?

(2) In fact I mainly care about how to prove it when $T$ is a symmetric matrix, so is there an easier way to prove the matrix version of this theorem?

(3) If possible, I hope some one can provide me with some reference about Riesz-Thorin theorem and some related topics so that I can learn more. (matrix version is enough but I would be glad to learn the results in more general version)

Comment: I am not finding there any statement that the real and complex versions of the norm are the same.

Comment: @losifPinelis Me too, so I am a little doubt about this proof... or are there easier way to prove this theorem for the case $T$ is a symmetric matrix?

Comment: If you don't see such a statement there (in the lecture notes?), then what is your question?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sorry I didn't state it clearly. I have changed my statement and listed my questions above.

Comment: The formulation of the question seems to indicate somekind of misunderstanding: the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the linked notes is the underlying measure space of $L_p$. I can't see why the measure space $\mathbb{R^n}$ should be changed to $\mathbb{C}^n$ anywhere in the argument.

Comment: @JochenGlueck By definition $N_0$ is the operator norm between the space of real functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, while in the proof the function $f_{yi}$ are complex in general, we can't immediately claim they are the same, as the example showed below. You can check it in matrix case.

Comment: @aurora_borealis: Hmm... What makes you so sure that the $L^p$-spaces in the notes you linked are supposed to consist of real-valued functions rather than of complex-valued functions? As far as I can see, this is not clarified in the notes. But anyway, the norm of an operator on a real-valued $L^p$-space does indeed coincide with the norm of the canonical extension of this operator to the complex-valued $L^p$-space (see my comments below Iosif Pinelis' answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your Question (3): A nice proof of the Riesz--Thorin theorem is given in Section 3.5 in [Lax's book](https://bookstore.ams.org/ulect-58/). A chapter devoted to interpolation of linear operators, including different versions of the Riesz--Thorin theorem, with further references therein, is contained in [Mashreghi's book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Representation_Theorems_in_Hardy_Spaces.html?id=PvM4VJlKcnkC) as Chapter 8.

As for your Question (1), as Jochen Glueck commented, you probably meant $L_p(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$ and $L_p(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb C)$ instead of $L_p(\mathbb R^n)$ and $L_p(\mathbb C^n)$, respectively. If so, the answer to your Question 1 is negative. Indeed, let $\ell_{2,p}$ denote the space $\mathbb R^2$ with the $\ell_p$ norm. 
Since $\ell_{2,p}$ can be isometrically embedded into $L_p(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$, we may restrict the consideration to $2\times2$ matrices $T$ with the corresponding operator norms $\|T\|_{p,q}$, $\|T\|_{p_0,q_0}$, $\|T\|_{p_1,q_1}$.

Then we find that the inequality 
$$\|T\|_{p,q}\le\|T\|_{p_0,q_0}^{1-t}\|T\|_{p_1,q_1}^t \tag{1}
$$ 
fails to hold if
$$T=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 0.448531 & 0.812143 \\
 -0.772457 & 0.469272 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and 
$$(p_0, q_0, p_1, q_1, t)=(3.99136, 1.32751, 8.82177, 1, 0.854335); 
$$
then the ratio of the left-hand side of (1) to its right-hand side is about $1.00041>1$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your answer to Question (1): If $T$ is an operator on a real-valued $L^p$-space, then the operator norm of $T$ coincides with the operator norm of the canonical extension of $T$ to the complex-valued $L^p$-space. Thus, the Riesz-Thorin theorem is certainly also true on real-valued $L^p$-spaces.

Comment: @JochenGlueck : "If $T$ is an operator on a real-valued $L^p$-space, then the operator norm of $T$ coincides with the operator norm of the canonical extension of $T$ to the complex-valued $L^p$-space." Why would that be so? In fact, for the operator (given by matrix) $T$ in my answer, its "real" norm is about $0.903636$ of its "complex" norm -- this is how that $T$ was found. Also, you are welcome to check the calculations.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you!

Comment: @IosifPinelis: A proof for the assertion I mentioned can, for instance, be found in Proposition 2.1.1 of [these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5425). Alternatively, you can also refer to [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512608). [to be continued].

Comment: [continuation] I do not have checked your computations numerically, yet - but anyway, may I ask by which algorithm you computed the matrix norms in your example? Even for $2 \times 2$-matrices, computing a good approximation of the complex operator norm by brute force methods seems to demand of a lot of computational resources since you need a very dense grid on the two-dimensional complex unit ball. Or am I just being ignorant, and there is a good way to compute the complex $\ell^p$-operator norm of small matrices analytically (without using that is coincides with the real operator norm)?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thanks for your reference which help me understand what I originally want to know(when $T$ is a symmetric matrix and $p$ equals to $q$). To sum up your two links, they tell us the real norm and complex norm are coincide when $p=q$, and $\|T\|_{\mathbb{C}}\leq 2\|T\|_{\mathbb{R}}$ in general. And this result does not contradict with the numerical example introduced above.

Comment: @aurora_borealis: Ah, I see. Somehow, I only had the case $p = q$ in mind, while $p \not= q$ in Iosif Pinelis's example (I actually did not notice that - which indicates that I should have thought more carefuly about the example before posting a comment).

Comment: By the way, I would still be very interested to learn how the complex matrix norms in the above example were computed.